# C# Webapi attribute routing is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have two different webapi controllers with actions as shown below. For some reason i keep getting "Multiple controller types were found that match the URL...." exception. Can anyone help me to figure out what i am doing wrong here?

ControllerA

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("clips/{Id}", Name = "GetById")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string Id)
{

}
```

*Id is alphanumeric and it always starts with a number

ControllerB

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("clips/product", Name="GetXProducts")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetXProducts([FromUri]SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a regular expression to both routes to ensure that it is chosen when the appropriate parameter is passed:

```
[Route(@"clips/{Id:regex([0-9]*[A-Z0-9]*)}", Name = "GetById")]
```

You will need to apply a similar expression to the other route to exclude these hits.

But I agree with @ryancdotnet that you should probably reevaluate your routes.

Comment: Thanks. But the requirement is what i have mentioned in the question. and there are couple of other routes which are like i) clips/AAA, ii)clips/BBB etc., is there any other way to achieve these kind of requirement please?

Comment: Im not sure I understand the full scope of the required URL scheme, but if you can't handle the different routes with regular expressions, you can always write a custom route restraint. See:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2.

Note that this example is for Web API, but similar classes exist in System.Web.Routing (IRouteConstraint).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is because your {id} on Controller A is of type `string`, and the Route for Controller B is essentially the same thing, as `product` is also a string, therefore Routing does not know how to differentiate between the two operations.

Comment: I would try reconsidering your URI path to see if there is a better resource representation of the objects you are wanting to return. Coming from a REST perspective, I'm not sure if `/clips/product` is a good resource representation. Perhaps something like `/clipproducts/` instead?